# Elements with common and separate properties in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a database with a table `post`, a user can submit many types of posts, and all these types share properties, and have properties of their own. For e.x: both video and standard posts have a `description`, but only video posts have a video link/file property.

What I did is creating a table post containing the common properties, like the `creationDate` and `description`.

And I created other tables, containing the other properties, and as the number of post types grows, I think I will have to add more tables.

Of course, the problem with this design is that when I want to retrieve one post, I have to retrieve its data from the `posts` table, then use its `ID` and `Type` to retrieve data from the type table (ex : videos table). And when I want to retrieve data of different types in one page I'll have to handle many tables.

Which seems not to be practical since I'm working with PHP/MySQL in an Apache server.

Is there any other better idea I can implement to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design follows the technique described in [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance).  There is an outline of the technique in the info tab.

You might want to explore using [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key) as a way to speed things up, and as a way to use post-id as a FK without having to have a different FK type for each post type.  It also speeds up joins.

The down side is that you will have to add a new table whenever you discover a new post type.  But then, if you were building an object model you would have to add a new subclass at the same discovery.

Comment: Thanks my friend,  I will try using the shared primary key, Of course I consider creating subClasses since I'm using POO/MVC model. Thanks again

Comment: Generally, the effects of the database design appears once the website grows. I can't see effect of this optimization now.